# How to use pagination for custom taxonomy archive?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type of flower and assigned flower-category taxonomy to it, I managed to create the pagination for the archive page. I works as expected.
Then I made a copy of the archive.php and named it taxonomy-flower-category.
The main loop looks like this:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'flower',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
        'tax_query' => array(
           array(
             'taxonomy' => 'flower-category',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $term->slug
             )
           )
         );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

       while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: `taxonomy` is not a valid argument. You need to use the `tax_query` array. Also, there should be no reason at all to use the `WP_Query` like that on the archive template. You should only need to use the default query since the main loop will only pull posts from that custom taxonomy on that template.

Comment: and if I don't use wp_query on the archive page, how can I set the maximum numer of posts per page ? without the query it will be default.

Comment: You use `pre_get_posts`. Also, please remove all this code from the comments and edit your question to include it. Much easier to read :)

Comment: problem solved. pre_get_posts was what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! `pre_get_posts` is the way to go when dealing with minor changes to the default loop.